# Display SQL information of user based on username in WPF App

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a WPF application were-in a user creates an account and can log-in with their username and password. When the user successfully logs in their Username and other details that they entered whiles signing up should be displayed on the next page. So far when I do it the only thing that shows up is the info of the first registered user no matter what Username or Password is used but it should be based on who's logged in.
Better explained, There's User A and User B, when User A logs in his info is displayed, when User B logs in, User A's info is still displayed no matter what, I want the info of User B(and all subsequent Users) to show when his specific Username is entered.

**C# for Sign Up Command**

```
private void SubmitBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbStudentName.Text == "" || pbPassword.Password == "" || tbSchoolName.Text == "" || tbHouseName.Text == ""
                || tbProg.Text == "" || tbPhoneNumber.Text == "" || tbAddress.Text == "")
            {
                var dim = new Dim();
                dim.Show();
                this.Effect = new BlurEffect();

                var cmb = new Custom_MessageBoxes.CustomMsgBox2();
                cmb.ShowDialog();

                this.Effect = null;
                dim.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                Connect obj = new Connect();
                obj.conn.ConnectionString = obj.locate;
                obj.conn.Open();
                string InsertUser = "INSERT INTO tblSignUp values ('"+tbStudentName.Text+ "', '" + tbSchoolName.Text + "', '" + tbHouseName.Text + "', '" + tbProg.Text + "', '" + tbPhoneNumber.Text + "', '" + tbAddress.Text + "', '" + pbPassword.Password + "')";
                obj.cmd.Connection = obj.conn;
                obj.cmd.CommandText = InsertUser;
                obj.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                obj.conn.Close();

                var dim = new Dim();
                dim.Show();
                this.Effect = new BlurEffect();

                var cmb = new Custom_MessageBoxes.RegistrationComplete();
                cmb.ShowDialog();

                this.Effect = null;
                dim.Close();
                Clear();
            }
        }
```

**C# for Sign In Command**

```
//Sign In button click event
        private void UserSignInBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


            try
            {
                Connect obj = new Connect();
                obj.conn.ConnectionString = obj.locate;

                obj.conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblSignUp WHERE StudentName = '"+tbID.Text+"' AND Password = '"+PB.Password+"'", obj.conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    // Custom Message Box and Dim Effect
                    var jim = new Dim();

                    jim.Show();
                    this.Effect = new BlurEffect();

                    var lsmb = new Custom_MessageBoxes.LoginSuccessfulMsgBox();
                    lsmb.ShowDialog();

                    this.Effect = null;
                    jim.Close();

                    var User_Homepage = new User_Homepage();
                    NavigationService.Navigate(User_Homepage);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Custom Message Box and Dim Effect 2
                    var him = new Dim();

                    him.Show();
                    this.Effect = new BlurEffect();

                    var rmdlgb = new ReturnMessageDialogueBox();
                    rmdlgb.ShowDialog();

                    this.Effect = null;
                    him.Close();
                }


                obj.conn.Close();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                using (EventLog eventlog = new EventLog("Application"))
                {
                    eventlog.Source = "SQL Error: From My Application";
                    eventlog.WriteEntry(ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error, 101, 1);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

**Page where I want user info**

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=HP;Initial Catalog=User_SignUpDB;Integrated Security=True;";


        public UHP()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Page1 p1 = new Page1();
            var pls = p1.tbID.Text;

            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            sqlCon.Open();

            string query = "SELECT * FROM tblSignUP WHERE StudentName = StudentName and HouseName = HouseName";
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);


            SqlDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                nameTxt.Text = (dr["StudentName"].ToString());
                hseTxt.Text = (dr["HouseName"].ToString());
                progTxt.Text = (dr["Prog"].ToString());
            }


            sqlCon.Close();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblSignUP
WHERE
    StudentName = StudentName
    AND HouseName = HouseName
```

There are no parameters being passed into this; it is just a hardcoded statement.

You're comparing equivalent fields in your `WHERE` clause, which makes it redundant, i.e. you're really just doing a `SELECT *` from the table. What you're reading into your application is therefore always just the first row returned.

What you need is something like:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM tblSignUP WHERE StudentName = @StudentName and HouseName = @HouseName";

SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);

createCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StudentName", StudentName));
createCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HouseName", HouseName));
```

The variables for `StudentName` and `HouseName` that are passed into the `SqlParameter` constructor (second argument), I'm assuming are already defined in your code somewhere.

Comment: Would this require me to use stored procedures?

Comment: The code I have posted will work as-is, but I personally do prefer to use stored procedures to keep the logic on the SQL Server. For using stored procedures, you can use something like `SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetStudent", sqlCon) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };`, and then add the parameters in the same way as I have done in my answer.